# Map operator [] does not work in while loop (expected primary-expression)

Tags: c++

Suppose that we have two following class.

```
typedef unsigned long ulong;

class State
{
public:
    ulong name; //name of the state

    State(ulong _name) { name = _name; }
    ...
};

class BetaPair
{
public:
    State* state_first;
    State* state_second;

    BetaPair(State* _state_first, State* _state_second){
         state_first = _state_first;
         state_second = _state_second;
    };
    ...
};
```

I have problem to compile the following code.

```
int main()
{
    map<pair<ulong, ulong>, BetaPair*> beta_set;
    set<pair<State*, State*>> worklist;

    //do something with beta_set and worklist

    for (pair<State*, State*> pair: worklist)
    {
        ulong n1 = pair.first->name;
        ulong n2 = pair.second->name;

        BetaPair* b = beta_set[pair<unsigned long, unsigned long>(n1, n2)];
    }
}
```

I am using g++ as compiler. I obtain two errors:

```
main.cpp:42:36: expected primary-expression before ‘,’ token
   BetaPair* b = beta_set[pair<ulong, ulong>(n1, n2)];
                                    ^
main.cpp:42:43: error: expected primary-expression before ‘>’ token
   BetaPair* b = beta_set[pair<ulong, ulong>(n1, n2)];
                                           ^
```

Can you please explain to me, why this error occurs and how this error can be fixed? Moreover, why if such a command move before the while loop and replace n1, n2 by some constant the compiler is fine (but if I again move the command with the same constant to inside to while loop then the error occurs again? Thank you.

Comment: the code you posted and the code in the error are quite different. Is this really the error you get from that code?

Comment: After `typedef unsigned long ulong;`, the types `unsigned long` and `ulong` can be used interchangeable and are considered equal by the compiler. The question is whether the compiler has seen the resp. `typedef` (in the right scope) when it complains about `ulong`.

Comment: Because you've obviously got `using namespace std` somewhere the compiler thinks you are using `pair` as both a template type name *and* a variable name (as in `pair.first` etc.).  Get rid of the `using` directive.

Comment: `std::make_pair()` might be worth to be mentioned. It can deduce the template parameters from arguments and may make code writing more convenient.

Comment: Remove `using namespace std;` and provide an MWE.

Comment: Yes, removing using namespace std; fixed the problem. Thank you.

Comment: @Scheff or `{}` initialisation

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've hidden the type name `pair` (from `std::`) with the variable named `pair` in your loop body.

Get out of the habit of `using namespace std;`.

You also don't need to name the types.

```
int main()
{
    std::map<std::pair<ulong, ulong>, BetaPair*> beta_set;
    std::set<std::pair<State*, State*>> worklist;

    //do something with beta_set and worklist

    for (auto pair: worklist)
    {
        ulong n1 = pair.first->name;
        ulong n2 = pair.second->name;

        BetaPair* b = beta_set[{ n1, n2 }];
    }
}
```

If you are using a C++17 or later compiler, you can get at your `State *`s directly

```
    for (auto [state1, state2]: worklist)
    {
        BetaPair* b = beta_set[{ state1->name, state2->name }];
    }
```